# How to get real image.size in diff devices(iphone4s/5s/6/iPhone6+)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

The original image file `PX as (24*50)`;

File name as

> "icon_detail_black.png"

in my project;

Using this code:

```
image_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_detail_black"];
```

Then the result in diff devices:

```
iphone 4s image_.size = (24*50)

iphone 5s image_.size = (12*25)  

iphone 6 image_.size = (12*25)  

iphone 6+ image_.size = (8*16.666666667)
```

why?

can we get the real original size?

i want get image size as is (24*50) (original image size). did have any solution? thanks

Note:

The "icon_detail_black.png" file as is "@3x" file,
i just set name "icon_detail_black.png",
i don't want to add the other file :
"icon_detail_black.png" and 
"icon_detail_black@2x.png"

i want just using one file (@3x) instead of three file, then using scale image to show in iphone4s/5s/6+ all of diff devices. so i need get the original image size.

**Solution 20150528**:

```
UIImage *image_s = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultImage_JNYJScrollImage"];
CGSize size_ = image_s.size;
CGFloat float_ = image_s.scale;

size_.width =  size_.width*float_;
size_.height =  size_.height*float_;
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 Details： see question details:

```
UIImage *image_s = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultImage_JNYJScrollImage"];
CGSize size_ = image_s.size;
CGFloat float_ = image_s.scale;

size_.width =  size_.width*float_;
size_.height =  size_.height*float_;
```

Answer (score 0):

File name "icon_detail_black.png" results in the IDE rendering this dimension for 1x. 
When you move to 5s, is scales to resolution for 2x, then for 6, same, and the for 6+ it scales it for 3x. 
You should have one image for 4s, one for 5s-6 ending in @2x and one for 6+ ending in @3x, each with the proper resolutions for the device.

For your case in particular, you should have:

- "icon_detail_black.png" 24x50px
- "icon_detail_black@2x.png" 48x100px
- "icon_detail_black@3x.png" 72x150px

added to your project (considering the 24x50) is the resolution for 1x

Comment: this  "icon_detail_black.png"  file as is "@3x" file, i just set name "icon_detail_black.png", i don't want to add the other file :"icon_detail_black.png" and "icon_detail_black@2x.png"  i want just using one file (@3x) instead of three file, then using scale image to show in iphone4s/5s/6+ all of diff devices. so i need get the original image size.

Comment: If you just want to use 1 file, you can only rename the resource to have the name @3x and the the compiler does the resizing by itself.

Comment: 2 Vlad: i did it too, but the result are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Name the icon as shown for 1x , 2x and 3x as shown:

- icon_detail_black-50w (@1x)
- icon_detail_black-100w (@2x)
- icon_detail_black-150w (@3x)

Then figure out what image you need at runtime:

```
    NSNumber *screenWidth   = @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    NSString *imageName   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name-%@w", screenWidth];
    UIImage *image        = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```